# Why does ImageFilter.BoxBlur give wrong results?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use the Pillow with some test data that I'm generating in black and white, pixel by pixel. I'd like to use this data to test out my [one pixel box blur](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFilter.html#PIL.ImageFilter.BoxBlur). I've got greyscale pixels stored in row-wise 3x3 matrix like this:

```
 5  10   5
10  15  10
 5  10   5
```

With a one pixel box blur, I'd expect the results to come out as:

```
10   9  10
 9   8   9
10   9  10
```

However, my result after calling `image.tobytes()` is an array of nine new lines (`\n`). Can anyone point me towards what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Kindly show your code if you'd like some assistance with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your expected output, but let's check the reality first:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

array = np.array([[5, 10, 5], [10, 15, 10], [5, 10, 5]]).astype(np.uint8)
img = Image.fromarray(array).filter(ImageFilter.BoxBlur(1))
print(np.array(img), '\n\n', img.tobytes())
# [[9 9 9]
#  [9 9 9]
#  [9 9 9]] 
# 
#  b'\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
```

The result is an array with all `9` – and when converting `9` to bytes, you get the [ASCII character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_code_chart) for a horizontal tab or `\t`. To be honest, I don't understand, why you get `\n` or line feed, which would be `10` converted to bytes, here!?

But, why the result at all? From the documentation (emphasis by me):

> Blurs the image by setting each pixel to the average value of the pixels **in a square box extending radius pixels in each direction**.

So, your matrix actually looks like this for calculating the nine (inner) pixels:

```
 5   5  10   5   5
 5   5  10   5   5
10  10  15  10  10
 5   5  10   5   5
 5   5  10   5   5
```

For each of the nine inner pixels, we get:

```
(4 * 5 + 4 * 10 + 15) / 9 = 75 / 9 = 8.333
```

It seems, we also have ceiling here instead of common rounding.

This may be due to:

> Uses an optimized implementation which runs in linear time relative to the size of the image for any radius value.

So, probably, some bit shifting magic instead of actual division or something like that.

You can also check, that border pixels are copied, and not mirrored:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

array = np.array([[5, 10, 5], [10, 15, 10], [5, 10, 5]]).astype(np.uint8)
img = Image.fromarray(array).filter(ImageFilter.BoxBlur(2))
print(np.array(img), '\n\n', img.tobytes())
# [[7 7 7]
#  [7 7 7]
#  [7 7 7]]
```

Set up the two possible 7x7 matrices like above done for the 5x5 matrix, and compare the results.

Bottom line: `BoxBlur` doesn't work the way you expected. And, it remains confusing, why you get `\n`, and not `\t`.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
NumPy:         1.20.2
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```